# Iterating over contents of an Hashmap and dividing them into categories

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have this code which as of now has an `hashmap` named `employee` of type `<String,Integer>` where **String contains the name of the department`in which an employee works and`Integer contains the age of that employee**. `I want to divide the employees age into different age categories(like 0-20,20-40 and so on) for each department`. The code that I have now is something like this:

```
       public void Employeeage()
{         
                categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel(); 




                QueryBean obj = new QueryBean();

                Map<String, Integer> employee = obj.getEmployeeAge();

                System.out.println("After accessing QueryBean");

                // 7 groups for age categories

                ArrayList<Integer> grp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> grp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> grp3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> grp4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> grp5 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> grp6 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> grp7 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                // for each department s, I want to divide employees into different age catgorie
                for(String s: employee.keySet())
                {
                for(Integer i : employee.get(s))   // Error thrown here that cannot iterate over here
                    {
                    System.out.println("Employee age is :"+ i); 
                    if(i.intValue() > 0 && i.intValue() <= 20 )
                        {
                        grp1.add(i);
                        }
                    else if(i.intValue() > 20  && i.intValue() <= 40 )
                        {
                        grp2.add(i);
                        }
                    else if(i.intValue() > 40 && i.intValue() <= 50 )
                        {
                        grp3.add(i);
                        }
                    else if(i.intValue() > 50 && i.intValue() <= 60 )
                        {
                        grp4.add(i);
                        }
                    else if(i.intValue() > 60 && i.intValue() <= 70 )
                        {
                        grp5.add(i);
                        }
                    else if(i.intValue() > 70 && i.intValue() <= 80 )
                        {
                        grp6.add(i);
                        }
                    else if(i.intValue() > 80) 
                        {
                        grp7.add(i);
                        }
                    }

                int size1 = grp1.size();
                System.out.println("Size 1 value"+size1);
                int size2 = grp2.size();
                System.out.println("Size 2 value"+size2);
                int size3 = grp3.size();
                System.out.println("Size 3 value"+size3);
                int size4 = grp4.size();
                System.out.println("Size 4 value"+size4);
                int size5 = grp5.size();
                System.out.println("Size 5 value"+size5);
                int size6 = grp6.size();
                System.out.println("Size 6 value"+size6);
                int size7 = grp7.size();
                System.out.println("Size 7 value"+size7);
                System.out.print("After inserting into groups");
                ChartSeries emp = new ChartSeries();  

                emp.setLabel("Employees");  

                emp.set("0-20", size1);  
                emp.set("21-40", size2);  
                emp.set("41-50", size3);  
                emp.set("51-60", size4);  
                emp.set("61-70", size5);  
                emp.set("71-80", size6);
                emp.set("80+", size7);

                categoryModel.addSeries(emp);  

            }
}
```

The code above is not complete in it's logic as I am not able to figure out a way to do so. **How can I divide the employees into different age categories for each department?**

**UPDATE:** I think I was not clear in the explanation, but what I want is the way to divide the employees into different age categories for each department. I didn't mentioned about the error in for loop outside the code area because, that was not my major issue here. Sorry for being a less clear

Comment: You haven't described what the issue with the above code is.

Comment: Well, your compiler is right. You can't iterate over a `Map.Entry` object.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I had mentioned it above and I have now highlighted my issue in the above post. I basically have problem in categorizing the employees in different age categories for each department

Answer (score 0):

You aren't totally clear in asking your question, (so turned out I tried to fix the wrong issue here) but it appears that you're kind of misusing the second `for` loop there.

```
 for(String s: employee.keySet()){
     for(Integer i : employee.get(s)) 
         ...
```

The first `for` loop is correct, albeit not as efficient as it could be. The issue is with the second `for` loop:

```
for(Integer i : employee.get(s))
```

If you look at the online javadoc, you see that `get()` returns the value that corresponds to the key that you passed in. So in your case, `employee.get(s)` returns an `Integer` object. And it doesn't make sense to try to iterate over a single `Integer` object. You probably just want to do

```
Integer i = employee.get(s).
```

instead.

A possibly more efficient way for you to go about this is to iterate over `HashMap.entrySet()`. This way, you get both the name and age in one shot without having to check the `HashMap` again for the age. So something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : employee.entrySet()) {
    String s = entry.getKey();
    Integer i = entry.getValue();
    // Rest of code here
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: By the way, if you ask a question in the future, please be specific with your problem; it makes it much easier to help you. You had the problem commented in your code, but there was no mention outside. Digging through code for problematic spots isn't fun an most people probably wouldn't bother. Imagine -- if someone came up to you with a bunch of code and just told you "I want it to do this, but it isn't working", it probably wouldn't be too fun figuring out what was wrong.

Comment: I have update the post above, highlighting the question for which I am seeking a solution

Comment: So do you want a separate group of ages for each department? Your code for splitting employees into different age groups appears to be OK at quick glance. However, there is one major issue with your code. Based on what you said `employees` meant, **you can only have one age per department**, as each department name maps to exactly one `Integer` object

Comment: yes, for each department I want to divide employees into age categories like 0-20,20-40 and so on

Comment: Then you appear to have an issue with your `HashMap`, because if your key is the department name and the value is the age you can only ever have one age per department